# Making the rightmost part of a input number field non-editable

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I want something like this:

[image]

Here the `%` sign will be in the input field by default and it cannot be edited or deleted. The user can only edit the number to the left of the `%` sign. When up or down arrow is pressed, only the number to the left of the `%` sign will increase or decrease.

For example, if I press the up arrow now, it will show

> 11%

, and if I press down arrow, it will show

> 9%

I have seen some examples for keeping the leftmost part of the input field non-editable, but here I need the rightmost part to be non-editable.

Comment: What have you tried add your code

Comment: I have no idea how to do it. I have found an example to make the leftmost part non-editable here: http://jsfiddle.net/Yt72H/ @shubhamagrawal

Comment: In the above given link the content inside a input field is alone restricted and in number field it accepts only number whereas in text box everything is possible. Hence try another method for what you are looking for

Comment: @lab11 https://jsfiddle.net/xn6pdr2g/ is this what you mean?

Comment: @engineeriscool Something like this, but with input number having up and down arrows.

Answer (score 3):

Please look into this [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aswathyb950/4tebhsmf/). I think this will help you.

```
<input id="edit_input" type="number"  style="width:80px;"></input>
<p>%</p>

input {
  float:left;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 0px 0 0px 0px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
p {
 margin:-4px 0px 0px -50px;
float:left;
padding-top: 5px;
cursor: default;
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
 font-size: 20px;
}
```

Comment: It looks good, but the % sign is not wholly contained in the input number field.

Comment: The % sign still is not contained in the input field. @AswathyBalan

Comment: Sorry I did not understand. What you mean by not containing?

Comment: Some part of the % sign comes out of the input field. I have got my solution. @AswathyBalan

Answer (score 1):

```css
    .edit-wrapper {
  max-width: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

.edit-wrapper input[type=number] {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.edit-wrapper:before {
    content: '%';
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="edit-wrapper">
<input id="edit_input" type="number">
</div>
```

Comment: % has fixed position  it can't be changed

Comment: Is there any way to align the number so that it appears just before the % sign? @tariqjaved

Comment: Wonderful solution @tariqjaved

Comment: Btw, I have a question. If I add this css to my JSP file where there are many more elements, will this "input::-webkit-outer-spin-button" be applied to all input fields? How to constrain it only to a specific class? @tariqjaved

Comment: it will applied only input[type=number]

Comment: or it can more specific .edit-wrapper input[type=number]

Comment: Though this worked on Chrome perfectly, this is not working in firefox. Can you please provide any other solution? @tariqjaved

Answer (score 0):

Just add the suffix via JavaScript on `keyup`.

```js
$('input[data-suffix]').on('keyup.addsuffix', function(e) {
  
  var suffix = $(this).data('suffix'),
      inputValue = $(this).val().replace(suffix, '');
      
  $(this).val(inputValue + suffix);
  
}).trigger('keyup.addsuffix');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="3" data-suffix="%">
```

Not that cool, I know. How about placing the suffix separated from the input like they do in [Bootstrap](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/input-group/#basic-example)? Would be more robust, I think.

Comment: The user can't edit or delete the digits easily. I have to input any additional digit after the % sign, which is not useful for general users. Moreover, as I move the cursor to the right of % sign, I can't move it to the left using keyboard.

Comment: Yea, I know. How about using a suffix separated from the input? See my edited answer. What do you think @lab11?